# How to change the color of Vim's (straight) underline?

Tags: vim

I've tried everything changing the color of this:

```
call s:h("Underlined",    {"fg": s:norm, "gui": "underline", "cterm": "underline"})
```

As well as all the colors of the link texts.

Does anybody know how to change it?

Here's a picture:

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For a long time, you couldn't; the underline color always equaled the text color. AFAICT, in terminals this wasn't supported, and for consistency, Vim also didn't offer this in GVIM.

With Vim 8.2.0863, the [`ctermul`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/syntax.txt.html#highlight-ctermul) attribute allows setting a separate color for *underline* / *undercurl* now. Apparently, this still isn't supported in GVIM, though (which I find odd, because Vim usually values consistency in features over fancy stuff (as explained by [`:help design-not`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/develop.txt.html#design-not))).

In GVIM, you could switch to the (GUI-only) *undercurl* attribute (mostly used for spell checking), which supports a separate "special color", set via `guisp={color-name}`; see `:help highlight-guisp`.

Answer (score 8):

For anyone finding that in 2021, you can use `guisp=red` in neovim at least.

For example I use

```
:hi CocErrorHighlight gui=undercurl guisp=red
```

to have red curly lines.

I am using NeoVim in the Xfce-Terminal.

Comment: Vim is also possible to display undercurl with `:highlight CocErrorHighlight cterm=undercurl ctermul=red`.

Comment: If you're running neovim inside tmux and trying to get single-colored underlines, see also: https://github.com/tmux/tmux/issues/3357.

Answer (score -1):

You can colorize underline only with `ctermul`(independent with `ctermfg`).

See [this commit](https://github.com/vim/vim/pull/6011) enabling that.